# Random Number Generator Javascript - Ranges

Tags: javascript, html

Looking for some guidance from those more knowledgeable than myself.

I'm writing a program that will prompt the user to click a button, which will then generate a random integer from 1 to 100.

I can manage that part fine. What I am struggling with is making the program print what range this random integer is in i.e. i<=33.

For example, when I click the button I want to see:

"10 is a number less than 33"

or

"55 is a number between 33 and 66"

Here is my code so far, I have put the code I am having problems with in comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>question2</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Click the button to display a random number from 1 to 100.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click here</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var text = "";
        var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;

        }

//          if (myFunction <= 33) {
//          text += ("<br>" + i + " is a number less than or equal to 33");
//          } 

//          if (myFunction > 34 and i < 65) {
//          text += ("<br>" + i + " is a number between 33 and 66 (exclusive)");
//          } 

//          if (my Function >= 66) {
//          text += ("<br>" + i + " is a number greater than or equal to 66");
//          } 



    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: actually, you're struggling with the concept of functions.  may i suggest taking a step back and playing for a bit with plain javascript without the confounding browser/DOM considerations?  nodejs in your shell would be a nice playground.

Comment: @justsomebody NodeJS doesn’t sound like “plain JavaScript”. The [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: @justsomebody I am totally new to this, thanks for the advice, I think I was trying to do too much at the one time. More researching is needed methinks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
    function myFunction() {
        var text = "";
        var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

        if (i <= 33) {
            text += ("<br>" + i + " is a number less than or equal to 33");
        } 

        if (i > 34 && i < 65) {
            text += ("<br>" + i + " is a number between 33 and 66 (exclusive)");
        } 

        if (i >= 66) {
            text += ("<br>" + i + " is a number greater than or equal to 66");
        } 

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }
```

Comment: @Xufox good catch, I copypasted and nominally reformatted the code without testing :)

Comment: this is exactly what I meant :) I had initially tried this method, can't see what mistake I was making from looking at your code but at least I know I was on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

You could test and if `true` display the result and exit.

```js
function getRandom() {
    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    if (i <= 33) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + " is a number less than or equal to 33<br>";
        return;
    }
    if (i < 66) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + " is a number between 33 and 66 (exclusive)<br>";
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + " is a number greater than or equal to 66<br>";
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display a random number from 1 to 100.</p>
<button onclick="getRandom()">Click here</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling variables from inside `myFunction()` outside of that function. Examples include `i` and `myFunction()`. It would be better to put the `if else` statements inside the main function.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    if (i <= 33) {
        demo.innerHTML = i + " is a number less than 33";
    }
    else if (i < 65) {
        demo.innerHTML = i + "is a number between 33 and 65";
    }
    else {
        demo.innerHTML = i + " is a number greater than or equal to 66";  
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display a random number from 1 to 100.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click here</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, that makes much more sense, I was looking at if else statements originally but I think, looking at your suggestion, that I was calling them outside the function. I'll get the hang of it eventually :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function isn't what you should be comparing against in your if statements.

But, I did throw something together let me know if this is what you were looking for.

You were on the right track.  Also on the middle comparison I changed you "and" to a shortcircuit "&&".

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xew8dvbd/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function myFunction() {
  var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  var text = "";
  if (i <= 33) {
   text += ("<br>" + i + " is a number less than or equal to 33");
  }
  if (i > 34 && i < 65) {
   text += ("<br>" + i + " is a number between 33 and 66 (exclusive)");
  }
  if (i >= 66) {
   text += ("<br>" + i + " is a number greater than or equal to 66");
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
};
$("#submit").click(myFunction);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sicae, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but I had to do this as a function expression rather than a function definition to make it work. Oddly, that's the second time this one worked as a gotcha in the last hour.

```js
myFunction = function() {
   var text = "";
   var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
   switch (true) {
     case (i < 20):
       console.log(i + " is less than 20.");
       break;
     case (i < 40):
       console.log(i + " is between 21 and 40.");
       break;
     case (i < 60):
       console.log(i+ " is between 21 and 60.");
       break;
     default:
       console.log(i+ " is over 60.");
   }
   };
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display a random number from 1 to 100.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click here</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You do not have to make this a function expression. Also, this doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for that reminder, I've edited the post to show a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks Snowmonkey, nice to get another perspective, I will definitely have a go with switch statements, using this solution to guide my attempts :)